# How does one filter a query set in django

Tags: django

Suppose you have a query set in Django how does one filter it, given that

```
    queryset.objects.filter(condition)
```

doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `queryset = queryset.filter(condition)`  See the [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) API